# wxErlang fails loading driver

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets, wxerlang

After several attempts I finally managed to compile and install both wxWidgets 2.8.11 and Erlang R13B04 with wxErlang on my Mac OS X, Version 10.4.11. However, testing wxErlang fails immediately:

```
1> wx:new().

 = ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jul-2010::18:37:23 === WX failed loading
 "wxe_driver"@"/usr/local/lib/erlang/li/wx-0.98.5/priv/i386-apple-darwing8.11.1"
 ** exception error:
 {load_driver,
  "dlopen(/usr/local/lib/erlang/li/wx-0.98.5/priv/i386-apple-darwin8.11.1/wxe_driver.so,
 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5wxApp10InitializeERiPPw\n Referenced from:
 /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/wx-0.98.5/priv/i386-apple-darwin8.11.1/wxe_driver.so\n
 Expected in: flat namespace\n"} in function wxe_server:start/0 in call
 from wx:new/1
```

I did see the thread "wxErlang" from Jun 7, 2009 on this mailing list. I did retry following it's advise (ensuring wxWidgets build directory is first in the path), but it didn't make any difference.

Any suggestions?

oTool -L says:

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 128.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 88.3.11)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1327.73.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 533.16.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Ciao,
Olaf

Comment: What does `otool -L /usr/local/lib/erlang/li/wx-0.98.5/priv/i386-apple-darwin8.11.1/wxe_driver.so` say?

Comment: Hm, there are no wx libraries listed there.  Was there anything wx-related in the output from ./configure when you built Erlang?  Or maybe in otp_src_R13B04/lib/wx/config.log?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by the command

`./configure --enable-m32-build`.

It worked on my Mac with Lion (OSX 10.7.2)

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Erlang 18.2. The output of `otool -L` is similar to Olaf's (it doesn't list anything related to Wx). Any suggestions?